# compare 2 csv file and get me output in the empty column using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 CSV files. 1st CSV file contains

| ID | Subnet | Subnet IP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | Net-prod-MT1 | 192.168.0.1/28 |
| xyz | Net-prod-DB1 | 192.168.0.16/28 |
| xyz | Net-prod-win1 | 192.168.0.32/28 |
| xyz | Net-prod-DB2 | 192.168.0.48/28 |
| xyz | Net-DR-MT1 | 192.168.1.1/28 |
| xyz | Net-DR-DB1 | 192.168.1.16/28 |
| xyz | Net-DR-Win1 | 192.168.1.32/28 |

2nd csv file contains

| ID | DR_sec_grp | Prod_sec_grp | Sec_typ | src/dest IP | Subnet | dr_subnet | proto | src_range | Dst_range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz |  | SG-prod-mt1-01 | outgoing | 192.168.0.16/28 |  |  | tcp | ALL | 1521 |
| xyz |  | SG-prod-DB1-01 | incoming | 192.168.0.1/28 |  |  | tcp | ALL | 1521 |
| xyz |  | SG-prod-DB1-01 | outgoing | 192.168.0.35/32 |  |  | imcp | ALL |  |
| xyz |  | SG-Prod-DB2-01 | outgoing | 192.168.0.10/32 |  |  | all |  |  |
| xyz |  | SG-prod-DB1-01 | incoming | 132.169.0.1/28 |  |  | tcp | ALL | 1521 |

I want these 2 CSV files to be compared and update the DR_sec_grp, Subnet, dr_subnet on the 2nd CSV file like this.

| ID | DR_sec_grp | Prod_sec_grp | Sec_typ | src/dest IP | Subnet | dr_subnet | proto | src_range | Dst_range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | Net-DR-MT1 | SG-prod-mt1-01 | outgoing | 192.168.0.16/28 | Net-prod-DB1 | Net-DR-DB1 | tcp | ALL | 1521 |
| xyz | Net-DR-DB1 | SG-prod-DB1-01 | incoming | 192.168.0.1/28 | Net-prod-MT1 | Net-DR-MT1 | tcp | ALL | 1521 |
| xyz | Net-DR-DB1 | SG-prod-DB1-01 | outgoing | 192.168.0.35/32 | Net-prod-win1 | Net-DR-Win1 | imcp | ALL |  |
| xyz | Net-DR-DB1 | SG-Prod-DB2-01 | outgoing | 192.168.0.48/28 | Net-prod-DB2 | Net-DR-DB1 | all |  |  |
| xyz | Net-DR-DB1 | SG-prod-DB1-01 | incoming | 132.169.0.1/28 | 132.169.0.1/28 | 132.169.0.1/28 | tcp | ALL | 1521 |

1. From the above CSV file, you can see "Prod_sec_grp" is changed to subnet and updated in "DR_sec_grp"
2. by comparing the data from "src/dest IP" with 1st CSV, I find the corresponding subnet and add them in "Subnet" and then the prod subnets are changed to the corresponding DR subnet.
3. if primary has 2 DB security groups, but if we have only 1, then change Net-prod-DB2 to Net-DR-DB1
4. if the src/dest IP is not part of 1st CSV file subnet IP range, then append the same value in "Subnet" & "dr_subnet"

python to filter subnet:

```
import re
import csv
cname=input("Enter the customer name:")
network_filename = "home/Documents/network_resources_1.csv"
target_filename = "home/Documents/subnet.csv"
target_file_data = open(target_filename,"w")
field_sep = ","
header ="Subnet,ID,Customer_name,Subnet,subnet_IP"
target_file_data.write(header+"\n")
for line in open(network_filename).readlines():
    if cname.lower() in line and line.startswith("SUBNET"):
        if re.search("CS", line):
            IDname = line.split(',')[1]
            subnetname = line.split(',')[7]
            subnet_IP = line.split(',')[9]
            if IDname and subnetname and subnet_IP:
                outline =  "{}{}".format("SUBNET",field_sep)
                outline =  "{}{}{}".format(outline,IDname,field_sep)
                outline =  "{}{}{}".format(outline,subnetname,field_sep)
                outline =  "{}{}".format(outline,subnet_IP)
                #print(outline.strip())
                target_file_data.write(outline.strip() + "\n")
target_file_data.close()
```

Comment: from the CSV file I have used re.search to filter subnet and put them to 1.csv and Seclist to 2.csv. using the data frame I have inserted 1 empty columns before "Prod_sec_grp" and 2 empty columns after src/dest IP.  I tried to pd.merge to match columns b/w 1.csv and 2.csv. but I am not getting the output as I needed. I am a beginner in python and I need some help in finding a solution.

Comment: I meant show us your Python code.  Read your first CSV in to a dictionary, where the key is the subnet IP and the value is the subnet name.  That gives you an easy lookup.

Comment: No, edit the question and add the code there, so you can format it.

Comment: The 4th row of your input data doesn't match the 4th row of your output data.  The subnet doesn't match.

Comment: You have too many rules you haven't defined.  What are "security groups"?  Are the "prod" and "DR" names somehow related?  How do we know that?

Comment: in the n/w table. you have Subnet and Subnet IP's. Each subnet contains 5 security groups. Each security group can accommodate a certain amount of security rules in it (both incoming and outgoing). example: net-prod-mt1 (subnet) contains 5 SG (SG-prod-mt1-01, SG-prod-mt1-02, SG-prod-mt1-03,..)

Comment: ip ending with /32 is the host IP. if the host IP matches the nearest subnet IP. it should update the subnet IP. if it does not then print the same IP to the next column. EG: 192.168.0.35/32 (host IP) comes under the subnet range Net-prod-win1. so it updates this in the subnet. If it does not match the subnet then print same to the next column

Answer (score 1):

Here is a first approximation.  Your rules are still very loose.  It's not at all clear why line 4 produces a mix of DB1 and DB2 names, even after I fix the error in the subnet.  Also, you are not really doing subnet matching; you are only doing string comparison.  My code is checking "is this IP within this subnet", so it works even with the individual hosts.

Given these two CSV files:

```
C:\tmp>type x.csv
ID,Subnet,Subnet IP
xyz,Net-prod-MT1,192.168.0.1/28
xyz,Net-prod-DB1,192.168.0.16/28
xyz,Net-prod-win1,192.168.0.32/28
xyz,Net-prod-DB2,192.168.0.48/28
xyz,Net-DR-MT1,192.168.1.1/28
xyz,Net-DR-DB1,192.168.1.16/28
xyz,Net-DR-Win1,192.168.1.32/28

C:\tmp>type y.csv
ID,DR_sec_grp,Prod_sec_grp,Sec_typ,src/dest IP,Subnet,dr_subnet,proto,src_range,Dst_range
xyz,,SG-prod-mt1-01,outgoing,192.168.0.16/28,,,tcp,ALL,1521
xyz,,SG-prod-DB1-01,incoming,192.168.0.1/28,,,tcp,ALL,1521
xyz,,SG-prod-DB1-01,outgoing,192.168.0.35/32,,,imcp,ALL,
xyz,,SG-prod-DB2-01,outgoing,192.168.0.48/28,,,all,,
xyz,,SG-prod-DB1-01,incoming,132.169.0.1/28,,,tcp,ALL,1521
```

And this source:

```
import csv

def convert_subnet(ip):
    ip, bits = ip.split('/')
    a,b,c,d = [int(i) for i in ip.split('.')]
    mask = 0xffffffff ^ ((1 << (32 - int(bits))) - 1)
    return (a<<24)|(b<<16)|(c<<8)|d, mask

def compare_subnets(a,b):
    return (a[0] & a[1]) == (b[0] & a[1])

def find_subnet(rows, needle):
    for row in rows:
        if compare_subnets( row[0], needle ):
            return row
    return None

def sg_to_dr( sg ):
    if sg.lower().startswith('sg-prod'):
        return 'Net_DR-' + sg[8:-3]
    return 'Net-DR-DB1'

f1 = csv.DictReader( open("x.csv") )
lookup = []
for row in f1:
    lookup.append( (convert_subnet(row["Subnet IP"]), row["Subnet"]) )

f2 = csv.DictReader(open("y.csv"))
outs = []
for row in f2:
    match = find_subnet( lookup, convert_subnet(row['src/dest IP'] ))
    print(row['src/dest IP'], match)
    if match:
        row['Subnet'] = match[1]
        row['DR_sec_grp'] = sg_to_dr(row['Prod_sec_grp'])
        row['dr_subnet'] = match[1].replace('prod','DR')
    else:
        row['Subnet'] = row['dr_subnet'] = row['src/dest IP']
        row['DR_sec_grp'] = 'Net-DR-DB1'
    outs.append(row)

f3 = csv.DictWriter( open('xy.csv','w'), fieldnames=outs[0].keys() )
f3.writeheader()
f3.writerows(outs)
```

The resulting CSV file is this:

```
ID,DR_sec_grp,Prod_sec_grp,Sec_typ,src/dest IP,Subnet,dr_subnet,proto,src_range,Dst_range
xyz,Net_DR-mt1,SG-prod-mt1-01,outgoing,192.168.0.16/28,Net-prod-DB1,Net-DR-DB1,tcp,ALL,1521
xyz,Net_DR-DB1,SG-prod-DB1-01,incoming,192.168.0.1/28,Net-prod-MT1,Net-DR-MT1,tcp,ALL,1521
xyz,Net_DR-DB1,SG-prod-DB1-01,outgoing,192.168.0.35/32,Net-prod-win1,Net-DR-win1,imcp,ALL,
xyz,Net_DR-DB2,SG-prod-DB2-01,outgoing,192.168.0.48/28,Net-prod-DB2,Net-DR-DB2,all,,
xyz,Net-DR-DB1,SG-prod-DB1-01,incoming,132.169.0.1/28,132.169.0.1/28,132.169.0.1/28,tcp,ALL,1521
```

Comment: You really made my day. Appreciate the prompt response and Thank you so much for helping me out with this!